# richfaces progressbar stays at 0%

Tags: jsf, progress-bar, richfaces

I'm trying to implement a progress bar in my web application, but can't get it work. I used the example on page

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=progressBar&sample=ajaxProgressBar&skin=blueSky

I get the button but when I click to begin stays at 0%. I tried to put the bean in session scope and still the same. Any idea?

This is the xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:atlas="http://atlas.core.componentes/jsf"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
>
<h:form id="form">
    <rich:progressBar mode="ajax" value="#{progressBarBean.currentValue}" interval="500" id="pb"
        enabled="#{progressBarBean.enabled}" minValue="0" maxValue="100">
        <f:facet name="initial">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText value="Process hasn't started yet" />
                <a4j:commandButton action="#{progressBarBean.startProcess}" value="Start Process" execute="@form"
                    render="pb" rendered="#{progressBarBean.buttonRendered}" style="margin: 9px 0px 5px;" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="finish">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText value="Process Done" />
                <a4j:commandButton action="#{progressBarBean.startProcess}" value="Restart Process" execute="@form"
                    render="pb" rendered="#{progressBarBean.buttonRendered}" style="margin: 9px 0px 5px;" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{progressBarBean.currentValue} %" />

        <!-- Update the progress for each AJAX update -->
        <a4j:ajax event="begin" listener="#{progressBarBean.increment}" />
    </rich:progressBar>
</h:form>
</html>
```

This is the bean:
    package app.jsf;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

/**
 * @author Ilya Shaikovsky
 */
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProgressBarBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -314414475508376585L;
private boolean buttonRendered = true;
private boolean enabled = false;
private int currentValue;

public String startProcess() {
    setEnabled(true);
    setButtonRendered(false);
    setCurrentValue(0);
    return null;
}

public void increment() {
    if (isEnabled() && currentValue < 100) {
        currentValue += 2;
        if (currentValue >= 100) {
            setButtonRendered(true);
        }
    }
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public boolean isButtonRendered() {
    return buttonRendered;
}

public void setButtonRendered(boolean buttonRendered) {
    this.buttonRendered = buttonRendered;
}

public int getCurrentValue() {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return currentValue;
}

public void setCurrentValue(int currentValue) {
    this.currentValue = currentValue;
}
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).